# sql management studio

Tags: mysql, sql

what is difference between primary key and unique key in defining tables in sql?

Comment: Likely a duplicate, but the primary key is always unique though not necessarily vice-versa.  You might use a unique key when you want some column, other than the primary key, to be unique.

Comment: What does the question have to do with the title?